# Question about solving partial differrential equation IVP

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Solve the IVP $u_t + (1 + x^2)u_x = 0$ where $u(x,0) = \arctan(x)$

I've found the characteristic curves, that being:

$$\frac{dt}{ds} = 1 \longrightarrow s = t$$

$$\frac{dx}{ds} = \frac 1 {1+x^2} \longrightarrow t = \arctan(x) + c$$

$$ \frac{du}{ds} = 0$$

but I do not know how to proceed from here. As in, what do I do next to find $u(x, t)$? I genuinely do not understand. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: The fact that your first sentence is not a sentence arouses some suspicions. A textbooks says "Factor the following polynomials." The student gets down to number 34, and it says $$ x^2+2x+5 $$ Then the student thinks all it says is $x^2 + 2x+5$. But there are words at the top: it says "Factor the following polynomials."

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't see how it's suspicious given the title of the question, but ok. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic curves satisfy the ODEs
\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{ds}&=1 \implies t=t_0+s, \tag{1} \\
\frac{dx}{ds}&=1+x^2 \implies \arctan(x)=\arctan(x_0)+s, \tag{2} \\
\frac{du}{ds}&=0 \implies u=u_0. \tag{3}
\end{align}
The condition $u(x,0)=\arctan(x)$ implies $u_0=\arctan(x_0)$ and $t_0=0$. Therefore,
$$
u\overset{(3)}{=}\arctan(x_0)\overset{(2)}{=}\arctan(x)-s\overset{(1)}{=}\arctan(x)-t. \tag{4}
$$
Let's check the result: Eq. $(4)$ implies $u_t=-1$ and $u_x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, hence
$$
u_t+(1+x^2)u_x=-1+(1+x^2)\frac{1}{1+x^2}=-1+1=0. \quad{\checkmark} \tag{5}
$$